# "To be worth something" vs. "to be worth it"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

*To be worth something* appears to translate into German only as:

> etwas wert sein

However, *to be worth it* appears to translate into German as either:

> es ist wert
>   es lohnt (sich)

Does that mean that the verb *sich lohnen* (or just *lohnen*) can’t be used for *to be worth something?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two slightly different usages of *etwas wert sein*.

One is the very literal meaning of *being worth [sth.]*, where the sth. would have to be replaced by a value or an object of equivalent value.

> Dieses Buch ist 100 EUR wert.
>
> Meine Tochter ist mir 200 Kamele wert.

(sorry for the latter example, couldn't come up with something better quickly)

There is also the more or less fixed expression

> Das ist (schon) etwas wert.

It means whatever *das* refers to is in some way valuable or helpful; it can mean all kinds of things, like a major task accomplished in a project or having a good first serve in tennis.

The second expression you're looking at

> Das ist es wert. / Es ist es wert.
>
> Das lohnt sich.

means exactly what you found, *it's worth it/the trouble*. *Das lohnt* is colloquial in my opinion, maybe also a regionalism. <strike>*Es ist wert*</strike> is simply wrong or at least missing an object (*Wen oder was ist es wert?*).

To answer the question at the end of your post: *sich lohnen* means that whatever is the subject of that phrase is expected to give you something valuable in return.

> Ein Studium an der Universität lohnt sich.
>
> Eine Investition in Gold lohnt sich.
>
> Ausreichend Schlaf vor der Prüfung lohnt sich.

Of course this implies that *sth. is worth sth.* (in the long run), but you would translate it into English as *sth. is worth it*.

Comment: Deine Tochter tut mir leid ;)

Comment: @tofro Du kannst nicht wissen, wie viel Wert ein Kamel in der Wüste ist :)

Answer (score 0):

"Etwas wert sein" is a *tangible* expression of x is worth some known quantity, such as 100 Euros.

"Es ist wert" is an *intangible* expression that "x is worth the trouble," or "X is worth it" for short. The "worth" is not specified, just understood.

I would use expressions with "lohnen" in the first sense, of tangible quantities.